# Issue with date comparison in Oracle 11.2.0.2.0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've encountered strange behavior of Oracle DBMS.
With the SQL quoted below result set is empty. If I delete either of "this_.order_date              >=" condition - it returns expected 2 rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT this_.id AS y0_,
   this_.order_date         AS y1_
 FROM flight_trip_orders this_,
   int_work_order_info iwoi1_,
   state_history_records cs2_
 WHERE this_.work_info_id           =iwoi1_.id
 AND iwoi1_.state_history_records_id=cs2_.id
 AND this_.order_date              <=to_timestamp('12/16/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
 AND this_.order_date              >=to_timestamp('12/13/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
 AND this_.order_date              >=to_timestamp('12/15/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
 AND rownum <=2;
```

How this could happen? Results of the query are different on two different Oracle instances, but both are version 11.2.0.2.0

Please do not suggest optimizing query and removing conditions - the query is generated and I have no power to change it.

EDIT:
Adding hint "ALL_ROWS" helps with the issue. The problem is that I can not add this hint in actual application, as explained above.

Comment: Did you mean either of the ">=" conditions? Because there is only one "<=" condition, and removing that would allow for any future dated record.

Comment: @DmitrySidorenko: Can you edit the question to include the data returned when the amended query does work?

Comment: @Glenn, you are right, either of ">="

Comment: `>=to_timestamp('12/13/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy')` **AND** `>=to_timestamp('12/15/2011'` doesn't really make sense. The >= '12/13/2011' will only be true for rows that match the second criteria as well. So the first one `>= '12/13/2011'` is not needed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your description of the problem is accurate, it sounds like it could be an optimizer bug.  Perhaps the redundant conditions are being handled badly and causing an incorrect filter to be used.  The first thing I would do is look at the execution plan for the full query and the query without the "12/13/2011" condition, and look for differences, particularly in the predicates being applied.

Comment: That was, in fact, optimizer issue. Oracle automagically reevaluated execution plan and problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the optimizer makes an error. Since you are running on 11gR2 you can use SPM to force the optimizer to use the same - accepted - plan for the sql, regardless of what else happens to statistics.

Enable sql plan management, accept your correct plan and make it fixed. Don't forget to document the reason, normally we don't want to have FIXED plans. See [Using SQL Plan Management](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optplanmgmt.htm)
for the details.

Answer (score 0):

`this_.order_date <=` might expect two rows but the other conditions are evaluated as well. So, one of the other conditions is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways records are being filtered off:

- with the WHERE condition
- through the join with the other tables: int_work_order_info and state_history_records

An EXPLAIN PLAN on both versions of the statement might show how filtering is applied.

But I would try removing the "DISTINCT" keyword along with the filters and see what difference it makes. Is it possible that there are multiple records sharing the same values for (flight_trip_orders.id and flight_trip_orders.order_date) but with different work_info_id?  Then which of these would the DISTINCT be chopping off?

Comment: Glenn, thanks for the answer. I tried removing DISTINCT, actually it was my first guess too. Did not help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the "DISTINCT" and then moving backward removing the state_history_records join, looking at the results, then removing the int_work_order_info  join?

Comment: Any progress on this? This is a really interesting puzzle. I'd love to know what is causing this.

Comment: Well, adding ALL_ROWS hint helped to solve the issue with SQL, but did not help with problem, since I cant alter SQL in that way.

The issue magically disappears from time to time. Seems to be related to Oracle statistic regathering or something like that.

I can post EXPLAIN PLAN here if you're interested.